# WSO2 Enterprise integrator Swagger TryOut not showing data

Tags: rest, api, wso2, swagger, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am busy with my internship and I am trying out WSO2 with setting up a sequence for an api. I created an api from an existing REST api, but when I try it out with Swagger it does not show any data.

Swagger config

[image: Swagger config]

Trying out swagger

[image: Trying out swagger]

It uses the correct curl but I cant let it been shown if I try it out.

correct API data

[image: correct API data]

I have no clue in how to move further with this. Would love if someone could help me out in the right direction.

EDIT/UPDATE-

I checked out the browser console (f12 on your browser) to check out what the exact problem is.
[image]

SOLUTION:

I had to allow origins for CORS in the StartUp.cs 
This allowed the client to contact it. I am not sure if this is a good solution but it worked for my Local WSO2

[image]

Comment: "Failed to fetch" most likely means a CORS issue. What's the full error message in the browser console?

Comment: I am sorry for my low knowledge. Where can I find the browser console? 
I am using the enterprise integrator, I start the service with CMD but cant really find a browser console that can give me errors from the api calls @Helen

Comment: [How to open the browser console](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/232313848-How-to-open-the-developer-console). Then do "try it out" again to see the error message.

Comment: @Helen It is indeed a CORS problem. Thanks for showing me where to get the error messages. Should have known it >v<

Comment: Did the issue get resolved?

Comment: I edited the post. For me I had it resolved but Im not sure if it a good answer